# Why is this api request returning time out ONLY when deployed online?

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests

Using Python Flask framework, this script waits on a GET request to fetch json from this [link](https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2018-19&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=) . This script works perfectly on localhost, but returns request time out when deployed on HEROKU.

Heroku deployment is 100% working [tested]

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Predictions(Resource):
    def get(self):
        url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2018-19&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision='
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = resp.json()
        resp.close();
        return data   

api.add_resource(Predictions, '/algpredictions')


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```